# Add a Prop() String Value to Host Class

Tags: jsx, stenciljs

I am new to StencilJS and JSX.

In my StencilJS component I have four props:

- disabled:boolean
- hasIcon:boolean
- iconOnly:boolean
- buttonType:string

In my render() function I have:

```
<Host class={{
        'btn': true,
        'disabled': this.disabled,
        'has-icon': this.hasIcon,
        'icon-only': this.iconOnly
      }}>
```

I would like to include the string prop called buttonType to the class but can find no documentation on how to accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in square brackets (a [Computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)):

```
<Host class={{
        'btn': true,
        'disabled': this.disabled,
        'has-icon': this.hasIcon,
        'icon-only': this.iconOnly,
        [this.buttonType]: true,
      }}>
```

You can also use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), for example to add a prefix:

```
<Host class={{
        'btn': true,
        'disabled': this.disabled,
        'has-icon': this.hasIcon,
        'icon-only': this.iconOnly,
        [`type-${this.buttonType}`]: true,        
      }}>
```

Note that this is a standard JavaScript feature, not specific to Stencil or JSX.